# SQL Server won't recognize \r?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Simple query :

```
UPDATE [WebERP].[dbo].[Users]
   SET 
       [ActiveDirectoryUser] = null

WHERE ActiveDirectoryUser='xxx\royin'
```

Error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Users_Update, Line 17
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression. The statement has been terminated.

I guess the problem is here :

[image]

it treats it as carriage return.

(if I change `\r` to `\b` it's ok.)

How can I fix it ?

Comment: That query could not possibly cause that error, there is no subquery in it. Also, SQL Server does not follow the `C` language rules for string processing.

Comment: @GSerg the problem was in a trigger behind the table. I disabled it and its fine. foolish me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your error in fact lies elsewhere - I assume you've given us a much simplified query which in fact doesn't reproduce the original error, or you've only given us one part of a bigger query.

For one thing - it says the error occurs in a subquery - your example doesn't contain one.

The code you've provided works fine on my adventureworks database:

```
update SalesLT.Address
set AddressLine2 = 'abc\nd'
where AddressID = 9
```

Does exactly as expected.

Comment: the problem was in a trigger behind the table. I disabled it and its fine. foolish me...:)